# 2 dimensional commutative $K$-algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show that if $R$ is a 2 dimensional commutative $K$-algebra then we either have $R\cong K \times K $ or $R \cong K[x] /(x^2) $. Apparently this uses the fact that $K$ is algebraically closed but I’m not sure where.

I guess what we are trying to show that if $R$ has $K$-basis $e_1 , e_2$ that in the first case $e_i ^2= e_i $ and in the second case $e_1 ^2= 1 $ and $e_2 ^2= 0 $. Or something like that. How to proceed?

Comment: It should only use that every degree $2$ polynomial splits. Example otherwise: $\mathbb C$ is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-algebra. In general, if $p$ is an irreducible degree $2$ polynomial over a field $K$ then $K[x]/p(x)$ is a field, and it is a counterexample.

Comment: Commutativity follows automatically. Here's a hint: the easiest way to find a basis is to take one of the elements to be the identity $1$. Then you take the other one to be any $x$ that is not a scalar multiple of $1$. So we have a basis $\{ 1, x \}$. Now what can you say about $x^2$?

Comment: What can you say about $x^2 $? It is a linear combination of $1$ and $x$.

Comment: @Ben Right. In other words, there is a polynomial $p(t) = t^2 + at + b$ such that $p(x) = 0$.  The cases come down to whether $p$ has a repeated factor in its factorization.